# How do I return a value from the success and error handlers in jQuery.ajax() to the parent method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok, for sake of argument, let's say that the AJAX call **MUST BE ASYNCHRONOUS**.

Basically, I have a jQuery AJAX call, and I want the success and error handlers to return a value to the parent method:

The code below does not work, since the AJAX call is asynchronous. Thus, the return value at the bottom of the function is returned before the repsonse is received:

```
var isValid = false;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myurl,
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: $myData,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        isValid = true;
    },
    error: function() {
        isValid = false;
    }
});

return isValid;
```

So, is there some way to pass a value BACK to the calling method for asynchronous AJAX calls?

Comment: Without settings `async: false` there would be no way to capture the success/failure before the end of execution of the method. The whole point of async is so that the script does not have to wait for the ajax request to be completed. If you need it to wait, set async to false. Otherwise, you will need to restructure your methods to work with the callbacks.

Comment: Would love to know why my question was downloaded.... What is wrong with my question? I hope it's not personal or something....

Comment: I need `async: true` because I'm using a "loading" image/dialog while the request is running, and this does not work with `async: false`. However, the calling page also needs to know whether the call was successful or not.

Comment: @Rodaine, I have restructured my javascript to use callbacks, and I will post the solution below. +1 for giving me the idea. It works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I have come up with that answers my question.... (Thanks to @Rodaine for giving me the idea!)

In the calling method, I am specifying a callback function. Here is the plug-in that contains the AJAX call:

```
function ajaxCall(options) {
    var url = options["url"] === undefined ? "" : options["url"];
    var addLink = options["addLink"] === undefined ? "" : options["addLink"];

    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var $formParamsString = $form.serialize();

    var aSuccess = [];
    var aError = [];

    if ($.isFunction(options["success"])) 
        aSuccess.push(options["success"]);

    if ($.isFunction(options["error"])) 
        aError.push(options["error"]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: $formParamsString,
        async: true, // Asynchronous to allow for loading image
        success: aSuccess,
        error: aError
    });
}
```

Now, when I call this function, I can specify a callback in the options Object:

```
ajaxCall({
    url: "myWebService.cfm",
    success: function() {
        alert("We did it!");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Try again, fool!");
    }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! I should have submitted the comment as an answer instead... :P

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Return isValid;
```

Is going to execute before the call completes, because it's asynchronous.

Use

```
async: false,
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. What you suggest is only a band-aid, and does not answer my question.

Comment: Well, I think I did answer your question (before you changed it)! The only way to return a value to the calling routine is to wait for the call to complete, i.e. make it a synchronous call. That's what sync and async are. If that's not good enough, you perform the action in the success or error method that you're expecting to make in the calling method. The calling method won't hang around waiting for a value, so you can't do it. Simples,

Comment: you simply repeated what I already stated in my original post "The code below does not work, since the AJAX call is asynchronous. Thus, the return value at the bottom of the function is returned before the repsonse is received". My question is how to return a value from the success and error handlers, NOT "how do i make this code work how i want?"

Comment: I hope this doesn't degenerate, but I told you; if you want a value returned from the event handlers, you must make it synchronous. That's the answer. Sorry if you don't like it, but there it is. If it's not the answer that you want, you need to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because isValid would be always false.

If you need to do something following success/failure you should do:

```
success: function(data) {
    isValid = true;
    otherFunction(isValid);
},
error: function() {
    isValid = false;
    otherFunction(isValid);
}
```

In this way you could handle the different cases

Answer (score -1):

Use synchronouse ajax call

set async to false.

Comment: Yes, I know this. What you suggest is only a band-aid, and does not answer my question.